# Maven no me realiza la fase de pruebas

Tags: maven, cucumber

Hice un proyecto en Java con maven para correr pruebas de [cucumber](/questions/tagged/cucumber) mediante junit, pero la fase de pruebas nunca se lanza.

### pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.github.javatlacati</groupId>
    <artifactId>unodostres</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <cucumber.version>4.7.1</cucumber.version>
        <maven.compiler.version>3.3</maven.compiler.version>
        <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
        <surefire.plugin.version>2.19.1</surefire.plugin.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>2.47.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${surefire.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.compiler.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>        
</project>
```

Al correr las pruebas mediante

```
mvn verify -B
```

Obtengo la siguiente salida:

```
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ unodostres ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.3:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ unodostres ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test (default-test) @ unodostres ---
INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ unodostres ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  1.359 s
```

Esta es mi estructura del proyecto:

```
unodostres
├───.idea
│   └───libraries
└───src
    ├───main
    │   ├───java
    │   │   └───com
    │   │       └───github
    │   │           └───javatlacati
    │   │               └───unodostres
    │   │                   └───pages
    │   └───resources
    └───test
        ├───java
        │   └───steps
        └───resources
```

¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

### Intentos

He logrado correr desde el IDE mi clase `UserHistoryRunner` que es la que tiene la prueba unitaria mediante el siguiente comando:

```
"C:\Program Files\Zulu\zulu-12\bin\java.exe" -ea -Didea.test.cyclic.buffer.size=1048576 "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.1.3\lib\idea_rt.jar=51804:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.1.3\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.1.3\lib\idea_rt.jar;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.1.3\plugins\junit\lib\junit-rt.jar;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.1.3\plugins\junit\lib\junit5-rt.jar;C:\Users\Ivana Martinez C\Documents\CoolBeansProjects\unodostres\target\test-classes;C:\Users\Ivana Martinez C\Documents\CoolBeansProjects\unodostres\target\classes;C:\Users\Ivana Martinez C\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-java\2.47.1\selenium-java-2.47.1.jar;C:\Users\Ivana Martinez C\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-chrome-driver\2.47.1\selenium-chrome-driver-2.47.1.jar;C:\Users\Ivana Martinez C\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-remote-driver\2.47.1\selenium-remote-driver-2.47.1.jar;C:\Users\Ivana Martinez C\.m2\repository\cglib\cglib-nodep\2.1_3\cglib-nodep-2.1_3.jar;C:\Users\Ivana Martinez C\.m2\repository\com\google\code\gson\gson\2.3.1\gson-2.3.1.jar;C:\Users\Ivana Martinez C\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-api\2.47.1\selenium-api-2.47.1.jar;C:\Users\Ivana Martinez C\.m2\repository\com\google\guava\guava\18.0\guava-18.0.jar;C:\Users\Ivana Martinez C\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-edge-driver\2.47.1\selenium-edge-driver-2.47.1.jar;C:\Users\Ivana Martinez C\.m2\repository\commons-io\commons-io\2.4\commons-io-2.4.jar;C:\Users\Ivana Martinez C\.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-exec\1.3\commons-exec-1.3.jar;C:\Users\Ivana Martinez C\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-htmlunit-driver\2.47.1\selenium-htmlunit-driver-2.47.1.jar;C:\Users\Ivana Martinez C\.m2\repository\net\sourceforge\htmlunit\htmlunit\2.17\htmlunit-2.17.jar;C:\Users\Ivana Martinez C\.m2\repository\xalan\xalan\2.7.2\xalan-2.7.2.jar;C:\Users\Ivana Martinez C\.m2\repository\xalan\serializer\2.7.2\serializer-2.7.2.jar;C:\Users\Ivana Martinez C\.m2\repository\commons-collections\commons-collections\3.2.1\commons-collections-3.2.1.jar;C:\Users\Ivana Martinez C\.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-lang3\3.4\commons-lang3-3.4.jar;C:\Users\Ivana Martinez C\.m2\repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpmime\4.4.1\httpmime-4.4.1.jar;C:\Users\Ivana Martinez C\.m2\repository\commons-codec\commons-codec\1.10\commons-codec-1.10.jar;C:\Users\Ivana Martinez C\.m2\repository\net\sourceforge\htmlunit\htmlunit-core-js\2.17\htmlunit-core-js-2.17.jar;C:\Users\Ivana Martinez C\.m2\repository\xerces\xercesImpl\2.11.0\xercesImpl-2.11.0.jar;C:\Users\Ivana Martinez C\.m2\repository\xml-apis\xml-apis\1.4.01\xml-apis-1.4.01.jar;C:\Users\Ivana Martinez C\.m2\repository\net\sourceforge\nekohtml\nekohtml\1.9.22\nekohtml-1.9.22.jar;C:\Users\Ivana Martinez C\.m2\repository\net\sourceforge\cssparser\cssparser\0.9.16\cssparser-0.9.16.jar;C:\Users\Ivana Martinez C\.m2\repository\org\w3c\css\sac\1.3\sac-1.3.jar;C:\Users\Ivana Martinez C\.m2\repository\commons-logging\commons-logging\1.2\commons-logging-1.2.jar;C:\Users\Ivana Martinez C\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\jetty\websocket\websocket-client\9.2.11.v20150529\websocket-client-9.2.11.v20150529.jar;C:\Users\Ivana Martinez C\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\jetty\jetty-util\9.2.11.v20150529\jetty-util-9.2.11.v20150529.jar;C:\Users\Ivana Martinez C\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\jetty\jetty-io\9.2.11.v20150529\jetty-io-9.2.11.v20150529.jar;C:\Users\Ivana Martinez C\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\jetty\websocket\websocket-common\9.2.11.v20150529\websocket-common-9.2.11.v20150529.jar;C:\Users\Ivana Martinez C\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\jetty\websocket\websocket-api\9.2.11.v20150529\websocket-api-9.2.11.v20150529.jar;C:\Users\Ivana Martinez C\.m2\repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpclient\4.4.1\httpclient-4.4.1.jar;C:\Users\Ivana Martinez C\.m2\repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpcore\4.4.1\httpcore-4.4.1.jar;C:\Users\Ivana Martinez C\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-firefox-driver\2.47.1\selenium-firefox-driver-2.47.1.jar;C:\Users\Ivana Martinez C\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-ie-driver\2.47.1\selenium-ie-driver-2.47.1.jar;C:\Users\Ivana Martinez C\.m2\repository\net\java\dev\jna\jna\4.1.0\jna-4.1.0.jar;C:\Users\Ivana Martinez C\.m2\repository\net\java\dev\jna\jna-platform\4.1.0\jna-platform-4.1.0.jar;C:\Users\Ivana Martinez C\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-safari-driver\2.47.1\selenium-safari-driver-2.47.1.jar;C:\Users\Ivana Martinez C\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-support\2.47.1\selenium-support-2.47.1.jar;C:\Users\Ivana Martinez C\.m2\repository\org\webbitserver\webbit\0.4.14\webbit-0.4.14.jar;C:\Users\Ivana Martinez C\.m2\repository\io\netty\netty\3.5.2.Final\netty-3.5.2.Final.jar;C:\Users\Ivana Martinez C\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-leg-rc\2.47.1\selenium-leg-rc-2.47.1.jar;C:\Users\Ivana Martinez C\.m2\repository\junit\junit\4.12\junit-4.12.jar;C:\Users\Ivana Martinez C\.m2\repository\org\hamcrest\hamcrest-core\1.3\hamcrest-core-1.3.jar;C:\Users\Ivana Martinez C\.m2\repository\io\cucumber\cucumber-java\4.7.1\cucumber-java-4.7.1.jar;C:\Users\Ivana Martinez C\.m2\repository\io\cucumber\cucumber-core\4.7.1\cucumber-core-4.7.1.jar;C:\Users\Ivana Martinez C\.m2\repository\io\cucumber\gherkin\5.1.0\gherkin-5.1.0.jar;C:\Users\Ivana Martinez C\.m2\repository\io\cucumber\tag-expressions\1.1.1\tag-expressions-1.1.1.jar;C:\Users\Ivana Martinez C\.m2\repository\io\cucumber\cucumber-expressions\7.0.2\cucumber-expressions-7.0.2.jar;C:\Users\Ivana Martinez C\.m2\repository\io\cucumber\datatable\1.1.14\datatable-1.1.14.jar;C:\Users\Ivana Martinez C\.m2\repository\io\cucumber\datatable-dependencies\1.1.14\datatable-dependencies-1.1.14.jar;C:\Users\Ivana Martinez C\.m2\repository\org\apiguardian\apiguardian-api\1.1.0\apiguardian-api-1.1.0.jar;C:\Users\Ivana Martinez C\.m2\repository\io\cucumber\cucumber-junit\4.7.1\cucumber-junit-4.7.1.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter -ideVersion5 -junit4 UserHistoryRunner
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolví el problema!

Se debe de especificar en el plugin de surefire la clase para ejecutar los `.feature` de la siguiente manera:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${surefire.plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*UserHistoryRunner.java</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```